# BigQuery - load a datasource in Google big query

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I have a MySQL DB in AWS and can I use the database as a data source in Big Query.

- I m going with CSV upload to Google Cloud Storage bucket and loading into it.
- I would like to keep it Synchronised by directly giving the data source itself than loading it every time.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a permanent external table in BigQuery that is connected to Cloud Storage. Then BQ is just the interface while the data resides in GCS. It can be connected to a single CSV file and you are free to update/overwrite that file. But not sure if you can link BQ to a directory full of CSV files or even are tree of directories.

Anyway, have a look here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-cloud-storage

Comment: had to go with Redshift, which accepts major database as data source.

Comment: So you decided against Google Big Query in favor of Amazon Redshift? Any reason why?

Comment: I couldn't set up the Datasource directly Big Query. But got a suggestion to use redshift or Open shift, Wherein I can directly synchronize form my MySQL DB. Appreciate your support